# Filter and Importrange not accepting multiple criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

I'm trying to use this formula but the last IMPORTRANGE criteria is not working:

Formula:

```
=IFNA(filter(SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE("URL","GA_Base!C:C"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","GA_Base!A:A")=H77), IMPORTRANGE("URL","GA_Base!B:B")="DP"))
```

This is the criteria that is not working:

```
IMPORTRANGE("URL","GA_Base!B:B")="DP"
```

Am I doing something wrong because it's multiple criteria?

Comment: Hi! This would allow for more help on this one if you shared a sanitized file...kind of a practice here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E6:E36, QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("1qsdPwnYRbmj5oW5f2QOwLfsPAloLsAHnoJWdF9cQELg", "Base!A:C"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col2 = 'DP' group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working =/. It gives me a blank cell.

Comment: @CarolinaSantos can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: yes, file Base: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qsdPwnYRbmj5oW5f2QOwLfsPAloLsAHnoJWdF9cQELg/edit?usp=sharing
Edit File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WGoeE_qQAG4TGyo5aC0HTq1d4FDn35vpLiYcaOBzkns/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CarolinaSantos answer and your sheet updated

Answer (score 0):

Try making a brand new tab on your spreadsheet and place this in cell A1:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "GA_Base!A:C"),"select Col1,SUM(Col3) where Col2 = 'DP' group by Col1",0)
```

then use the table that makes for some regular vlookups on the tab in question for your values in column H.